# SQL Server SMO TransferData() runs slowly

Tags: c#, sql-server, schema

I'm following http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1910 and the following code actually does work, but takes about 90 seconds to run.  The database schema has less than 10 (fairly straightforward) tables.  I'm not sure why it takes so long.  Any suggestions on how to debug this?

```
var host = "192.168...";
var user = "username";
var pass = "password";
var srcDbName = "srcDbName";
var dstDbName = "dstDbName";

var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(host, user, pass));

var srcDb = server.Databases[srcDbName];
var dstDb = new Database(server, dstDbName);

dstDb.Create();

var transfer = new Transfer(srcDb);

transfer.CopyAllTables = true;
transfer.Options.DriAll = true;
transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = false;

transfer.DestinationDatabase = dstDbName;
transfer.DestinationServer = server.Name;
transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
transfer.DestinationLogin = user;
transfer.DestinationPassword = pass;

transfer.TransferData();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should leave this code alone. You cannot improve it. AS I understand from the question you want to transfer tables/schema from one database to other .

Below options that I suggest :

**Linked Servers**

From SQL 2000 you should be able to connect directly to other database as a linked server. In the pros column this kind of direct access can be easy to work with if you don't have any other technical skills such as DTS or SSIS, but it can be complex to get the initial set-up right and there may be security concerns/issues.

**DTS**

DTS is packaged with SQL 2000 and is made for this kind of a task. If written correctly, your DTS package can have good error-handling and be rerunnable/reusable.

**SSIS**

SSIS is actually packaged with SQL 2005 and above, but you can connect it to other databases. It's basically a better version of DTS.